# How can I use Google Places API multiple times in a location aware app?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am developing an app which will give you nearby Mosques within 10 km of your current location. Now that the Places API allows a certain number of queries per day, I have used firebase to store nearby Mosques for a certain location and I first check if the data is in database or not before querying. But this still doesn't solve the problem. e.g. if a user is on the go the whole day then the results must be changing every single minute, according to his/her location. How can I achieve the desirable results?

As mentioned earlier, I am saving nearby locations in a database with their relative location (around which they exist). But this doesn't quite solve the problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Places API is a commercial offering - you are meant to pay for using it, if you want to make applications around it.

There's a certain small number of calls that you can do for free, but this is only meant as testing grounds or private use. I am no lawyer, but I would guess that circumventing the fee by scraping the map (like setting a bot to go around a country to build a database of points of interests) would be illegal and would probably get you a letter from Google saying you should stop.

Comment: Yes, it actually explicitly says in the license agreement that you are not allowed to cache the data, so if this is used in a comercial application it is at risk of getting sued or fined by google.

Comment: @JoachimHaglund Its not a commercial app. Just an academic project.

Comment: in that case i guess you just have to live with the restrictions, as it can get quite expensive with alot of calls if you sign up for a complete licence. You could show an alert in the application when you are out of calls perhaps, or setup a restriction that you can only make one call every 10 min or 30min or something if the data can not be gotten from the database/cache

Comment: @hafsa anyway: Places API is not meant to free. There are things that cost money: hosting, access to certain APIs, software licenses etc. Building an academic project does not mean you are going to get them for free (although for some, such as software licenses, this sometimes is the case)

Answer (score 0):

Use AutocompleteSessionToken class to generate a token and place it after your key , this token will reduce your usage because you can request the places api multiple times and still it will be considered as a single request. i hope this will help cause i didnt get your question very well. here is sample of the link:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=1600+Amphitheatre&key=&sessiontoken=1234567890.

For more details.see [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/session-tokens)

Comment: autocomplete does not get the full data for the places though, for example coordinates are not included when you only call the autocomplete, so this will only work for actually typing, sence its only names and ids you get. Its ment to be used for searching (autocomplete) as the name suggests, and when user selects a location you send that location to details api to get the coordinates etc.